# In an SQL table, I get the last column's last row value

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I want invoke the last column's last row value and display it in a textbox (`TextBox2.Text`) in C#.

Table details: In one event I inserted the row value so uncount rows insert into the table. I want to achieve in another (result) event to get last column's last row value... How is it possible, possibly explained with some code? Or is there some general syntax to get last row value?

Comment: Do you have any identity column on the table ?

Comment: @Roshan ty for reply ..No dont have identity column in this table

Comment: It is easy to get table's row count with out identity.

Comment: @Kostas ch can u pls explain brief..

Comment: Define "Last" row. Data in a table has no implicit order unless you define it. It is stored in the order of the clustering key, if you do not define an order by clause in a select, it is returned in any order the optimiser feels fit, unless you have a date column, or some other column that will identify the most recent row inserted, "Last" row is meaningless.

Comment: @GarethD s have the same doubt .. so only choose to code in c# with out query

Comment: @GarethD - Its C# in result event .. i cant use Sql Queary as u reply ,there is no definiton for tht last row to retrieve index.. so i go with m hasan answer partially ..

Comment: @GarethD Can u explain me wtih some more detail

Comment: If you are simply using a DataTable, and presumably in conjuction with the `DataAdapter.Update()` method, then you are correct, m Hasan's answer is pretty much there, although data in SQL has no implicit order, in a c# data table, the last row will have the highest index, so his answer works as far as I can tell. You could also use the [DataTable.RowChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged.aspx).

Comment: @GarethD if i use update query in this table i cant able to retrieve the whole statement of records in that table.. so i go with c# code. if anything want to improve in tht code am waitin for your explaination ty so much for ur reply here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch total rows and columns and pass these values as index to datatable `dtable`

```
int totalRows = dtable.Rows.Count;
int totalCols = dtable.Columns.Count;

string value = dtable.Rows[totalRows-1][totalCols-1].ToString();

TextBox2.Text=value;
```

Suppose your datatable `dtable` in C# contains these rows and now you want last columns last row value that is `col3` last row value which if you see in datatable below is **vgt**.

```
col1 | col2 | col3
 1      abc    pqr
 2      art    lmn
 3      yut    xyz
 4      btt    vgt
```

`dtable.Rows.Count` gives me number of rows which is **4**

`dtable.Columns.Count` gives me number of columns which is **3**

So to access the last row last column value we pass these values as index to datatable which is like a 2D array and since you know arrays start from index 0 , the actual address of last row last column would be `[totalRows-1][totalColumns-1]`

Comment: @m hasan.. ty i can found d core concept in ur reply for this issue

Comment: you want me to explain this ?

Comment: @m hasan  can u explain me

Answer (score 0):

SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;
This command will help you to access last row of any column.
just name of last column . and run

Comment: Its not possible,inserted more rows with login details so

Answer (score 0):

If the last column name is known and the rows have one unique id is int field which is not autoid or integer you can just do the above :

```
  string query = " select top 1 youlastcolumnname   from 
      FROM youtable ORDER BY youruniqueid desc";
```

C# code as asked:

```
 using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(yourconnectionstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query , conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                youttextbox.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: I need explanation in C# Code . can u explain wituh code

Comment: @user3563106 if the sql part fits it is easy to create c# code.

Comment: yep but i didnt use query .. i used code coz its a single event

Comment: I understand but i wont use queary

Comment: @user3563106 if you do not want to use the above code just use mhasan post.

Comment: Yes thank you so much for ur reply here if u like quote - upvote.. i want to get more knpwledge abt this.

Comment: @GarethD I cannot load the link. But if the youruniqueid was int i would mind how to get the last record. So i did ROW_NUMBER  as you correctly said for in order to get the last record. The other part of your commenct i couldn't understand :)

Comment: @GarethD in your demo you used uniqueidentifier. youruniqueid  may be string or what ever. If was string how i would get the last record?

Comment: @GarethD How i could get the last record of a table that the id is string? To to do ORDER BY with what? In your example if the uid was unique and you did not have th id column, only uid. How you could get the last record?

Comment: @GarethD Indeed is a waste of time. Have a nice day.

Comment: Dear @GarethD see that:declare  @t table
(
 name nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @t values ('kostas')
insert into @t values ('giorgos')
insert into @t values ('takis')
select * from @t
 ;with a as 
 (
   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ) AS Row,*
   FROM @t
  )
  
  select top 1 *  from a
  order  by Row desc

Comment: Same result as `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @T ORDER BY Name DESC`. - No need for ROW_NUMBER

Comment: @GarethD , kostas ch. if u like this question give upvote it ll help me to go for next level

Comment: @GarethD i Think you are absolutely right. It was in front of my eyes! Thx